# How to install WPF Toolkit(datagrid) in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I m a student and i m trying to create a wpf using visual studio 2010 (.NET Framework 4.0. ). I would like to use the DataGrid as i have seen in this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_fHht6J6xc&feature=related

My problem is that the WPF Toolkit cannot be displayed on my ToolBox. I download it from here  http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535 , i installed it and i can see it in the resources,But unfortunately i cant get the DataGrid in the toolbox!Please help, i have no time for my project and i have been confused!What steps may i have to do to install the wpf toolkit?Many many thanks!!

Comment: Are you building against .NET 4?  DataGrid is included in WPF 4, and does not need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Its already included! The DataGrid toolkit is for .Net 3.5 and VS 2008! Its part of .Net4 (which you must have to have VS2010):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=VS.100).aspx